# Set Input ref value for screen reader

Tags: reactjs, screen-readers, jaws-screen-reader, nvda, blueprintjs

I am running into trouble trying to set the input ref value on a blueprintjs `Select` component. Visually, the component works fine but I need the current highlighted option to be read by a screen reader. For some reason the screenreader(NVDA) reads the last selected/highlighted value instead of the current value.

[image]

Currently my code simply updates the input value with the highlighted option. Here is my code:

```
renderItem = (item, { handleClick, modifiers, query }) => {
    if (!modifiers.matchesPredicate) {
        return null;
    }
    const text = `${item.attributes.project_name}`;
    return (
        <MenuItem
            active={modifiers.active}
            disabled={modifiers.disabled}
            key={item.attributes.project_name}
            onClick={handleClick}
            text={highlightText(text, query)}
        />
    );
};

filterItem = (query, item) => {
    return `${item.attributes.project_name}`.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
};

setActiveItem = (item) => {
    let activeItem = item && item.attributes ? item.attributes.project_name : null
    this.inputElement ? this.inputElement.value = activeItem : null
    this.setState({activeItem})
};

render() {
    return (

        <Box style={{width: '100%', marginBottom: '10px'}}>

            {this.props.projects ?
                <Select
                    itemPredicate={this.filterItem}
                    itemRenderer={this.renderItem}
                    items={this.props.projects}
                    onActiveItemChange={this.setActiveItem}
                    inputProps={{value: this.state.activeItem,
                        inputRef: el => this.inputElement = el}}

                    noResults={<MenuItem disabled={true} text="No results."/>}
                    onItemSelect={this.props.onProjectSelect}
                    popoverProps={{minimal: true, popoverClassName: 'search-popover'}}
                >

                    <Button text="Select a Project" icon="projects" style={{width: '225px'}}
                            rightIcon="double-caret-vertical"/>
                </Select>
                : null}
        </Box>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Blueprintjs has a direcct way to do this. I'd recommend using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/). You can style the open state of the select and apply the onFocus to the the currently hovered element.